# MongoDB reject duplicates with compound unique index

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to reject duplicates when I save new documents.

My documents look like this:

```
{ "STATION_ID" : "KLFI",
  "TimeAsDate" : 1437656400000, 
  "TIME" : "231500Z", 
  "MYVISIBILITY" : 9600, 
  "SKYCONDITIONS" : { "1" : { "cloud_base_ft_amsl" : 5009.8424,
                              "cloud_base_ft_agl" : "5000", 
                              "sky_cover" : 3 },
                      "2" : 0, 
                      "3" : 0 
                     },
  "LATITUDE" : 37.07, 
  "LONGITUDE" : -76.37, 
  "_id" : ObjectId("55b0e0df80e44b30365e41de"), 
  "__v" : 0 
}
```

While importing new documents it could be, that there are some duplicates so I want do reject all documents, which have the same STATION_ID and TIME (only in the same document).
If STATION_ID is the same and TIME is different I want to keep it.

I believe I can do this with compound unique index like this:

```
db.meteo.createIndex({TIME: 1, STATION_ID: 1}, {unique: true, dropDups: true})
```

But it doesn't realy works how I want, it rejects too much entries, instead of having more or less 60'000 entries i now have only 7000.

I'm not a Javascript or MongoDB expert and I'm not shure to be on the right track, can somebody help me please?

Regards

Comment: You probably should have "TimeAsDate" in there as well as the first element in the compound index. It's rounded to days so it makes sese to include it. That said, I don't really know what this will do for "duplicates" as the granularity here is to the milisecond. So you would need a "lot" of inserts to make that an issue. What really makes a "duplicate" I somehow doubt it's the time data. I would check that to be sure what you think are duplicates actually are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I think you can use the upsert option on an [update](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/)

This allows you enter an update query, such as `{ STATION_ID: "KLFI" }` and pass in the document to update.

Using the `upsert : true` flag will mean that only documents where the update query is not met will be created as new documents, so your duplicates will not be created.

This assumes that if STATION_ID and TimeAsDate are the not changed, then the rest of the document is also not changed.